# UINavigationControllerPaletteClippingView covering UIImageView and receiving tap gesture

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift4, ios11

I'm implementing a tap on an image view to enlarge it, then tap to dismiss the enlarged image. The dismiss tap isn't working though. When I look at the view hierarchy I see that there's a UINavigationControllerPaletteClippingView over the image view that I think is receiving the taps. They mention a similar issue [here](https://github.com/willowtreeapps/Hyperion-iOS/issues/31) in iOS 11. I can't find hardly any documentation about this and am kind of lost. Here's my code:

```
@objc func enlargeImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let image = (sender.view as! UIImageView).image
    let enlargedImageView = UIImageView(image: image)
    enlargedImageView.frame = view.frame
    enlargedImageView.backgroundColor = .black
    enlargedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    enlargedImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let tapToDismiss = UIGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissEnlargedImage))
    enlargedImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapToDismiss)
    self.view.addSubview(enlargedImageView)
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
}

@objc func dismissEnlargedImage(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

**Update:**

[image]

Here's the view debugger screenshot.

I put a breakpoint inside dismissEnlargedImage and it's never reached, so I don't think there's an issue like that. And I declare both of the gesture recognizers inside separate functions so I don't see a way for the scope to be the problem.

Comment: did u solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

`_UINavigationControllerPaletteClippingView` was introduced in iOS 11 and, in short terms, handles the appearance of a search bar in a navigation bar added to a navigation item through its `searchController` property. It works in conjunction with the large titles and collapsing bars introduced in iOS 11.

You find sparse documentation about this class, because it is private to UIKit (i.e. you should not use it directly if you want to retain AppStore conformity).

That being said, it might be hard to analyze your problem without more context. Could you provide a screenshot of the layout debugger where you see the `_UINavigationControllerPaletteClippingView` covering the image view your are adding?

Is the image view added in a searchable screen. I.e. does the navigation scene include a search bar when you show the image?

I'll happily update this answer if additional context gives me (us) a clue as to where to look for the problem.

---

### Update

`enlargeImage` seems to be called by a `UITapGestureRecognizer`. Can you confirm that there is no monkey business involved as to how both of the methods are called and in which order, etc.?

What I mean by this:

- Maybe `enlargeImage` is called simultaneously with `dismissEnlargedImage` and for every tap you show and hide an image at the same time, giving you the impression of the dismiss tap to not work?
- Maybe the gesture recognizer calling `enlargeImage` is related to the gesture recognizer calling `dismissEnlargedImage` in such a way that having one prevents the other from firing?

Comment: I've updated the question with the info you requested